# what is <meta name="verify-v1" content="bGDK2jk+Vhn+Kk2NrZFue5EbYn1Fed4v/Ej+U2bg7wc=">

Tags: jsp, tags

In the following code:

```
 <meta name="verify-v1" content="bGDK2jk+Vhn+Kk2NrZFue5EbYn1Fed4v/Ej+U2bg7wc=">
```

what is 'verify-v1' and its associated content?

I have seen this code a few times in my program but couldn't understand what its for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What is it?

> The “verify-v1 metatag” is special metatag from Google. It can provide
>   you with comprehensive statistics and error information about the
>   pages in your site. You can either add the “verify-v1 metatag” to your
>   web page or upload a HTML File. I have found that simply adding the
>   “verify-v1 metatag” is easiest.

[Source](http://www.gettingindexed.com/Step5.htm)